# Converting R dataframe with NA in text column to Python with rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I want to convert an R dataframe to python using rpy2.
I don't know how to convert NA appearing in a text column to a Python value.

This is an example which shows my problem.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
ro.r('n = c(1,2)')
ro.r("b = c(NA,'def')")
ro.r("df = data.frame(n,b)")
rdf = ro.r('df')
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    df = ro.conversion.rpy2py(rdf)
```

Produces:

```
>>> print(df)
     n              b
1  1.0  NA_character_
2  2.0            def
```

A similar code with an old version of rpy2 used to work

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
ro.r('n = c(1,2)')
ro.r("b = c(NA,'def')")
ro.r("df = data.frame(n,b)")
rdf = ro.r('df')
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(rdf)
```

Produced:

```
>>> print(df)
     n    b
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  def
```

How do I get back the old behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug as of rpy2 version 3.5.14, which also appeared with the [numpy converter](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/changes.html#id11). Until it is fixed, you could use the deprecated `pandas2ri.activate()`.

```py
import rpy2.robjects as ro
ro.r('n = c(1,2)')
ro.r("b = c(NA,'def')")
ro.r("df = data.frame(n,b)")
rdf = ro.r('df')
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
df = ro.conversion.rpy2py(rdf)
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
     n     b
1  1.0  None
2  2.0   def
```

Note that instead of `NaN` the first value is `None`, but this makes sense since the values of column `b` are strings instead of numbers. If `b` was a column of number, e.g. `ro.r("b = c(NA, 3)")`, then you would get `NaN`.